# Fragment best practice - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am struggling with the structure of the fragment, Thing is... In Activity there is two fragments. One contains a list.  Call this `FragmentA`. The other contains detail.  Call this `FragmentB`.

With every list item in `FragmentA` there is a different view for `FragmentB`, so what is the preferred way to handle this kind of scenario?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the complexity of the app in question, I would suggest that each different view for `FragmentB` be represented in its own fragment.

The use the Fragment Transaction method to replace the placeholder (let's call this `R.id.fragment_container`) where `FragmentB` is with the appropriate fragment depending on your selection in `FragmentA`.  Something like this:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: But pay attention to different screen sizes and on small sizes start a new activity rather than commit fragment transaction

Comment: Absolutely, you definitely want to handle significantly different screen sizes, well, differently...

Comment: thanks for your help, I think this should work perfect with my case